# Andriod: Передать объект другому Activity без сереализации

Tags: java, android, многопоточность, activity, android-intent

Необходимо в Android передать сложный объект другому Acitvity.
Почему не выходит использовать Serialization или Parcelable и передать через Intent: я хочу передать класс TcpServer в нем у меня есть два вложенных класса-потока (Thread).

То есть этот класс TcpServer при создании запускает первый поток (он запускает ServerSocket и ждет клиентов).
При accept (подключении клиента) этот поток создает второй поток для конкретного сокета.
Дак вот в классе TcpServer я сделал метод write() который шлет всем текущим клиентам сообщение. И просто так сереализовать этот объект вообще не выйдет. И мало того - мне надо чтоб на втором активити был именно этот же объект (а не новый).
Как это можно сделать?
Цель: мне просто надо передавать сообщения всем клиентам с нескольких Activity.

Comment: Что мешает просто вынести это в фоновый сервис, как предписывает идеология Android? Activity вообще не должен делать чего-то долгого и тяжеловесного - он отвечает за пользовательский интерфейс.

Comment: Про сервис полностью поддерживаю, а для обмена между частями проекта рекомендую EventBus https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus/blob/v2/HOWTO.md

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть неправильный, но простой способ: Использовать статическое поле. И через это поле передавать\получать доступ к объекту.

Есть правильный, но более сложный способ. Это способ, описанный @SergeyRufanov:
Создайте сервис, который будет инициализировать и предоставлять доступ к нужному объекту, и вы сможете получить доступ к сервису из любого Activity при помощи биндинга.

Есть еще один способ, который по *правильности* встанет посередине между вышеописанными:
Хранить нужный объект в Activity, а передавать его во фрагменты. То есть перевести ваши текущие Activity на фрагменты, и создать одну новую Activity, которая будет хранить объект.

Еще раз повторю, правильным является именно второй метод, с созданием сервиса. Я крайне рекомендую именно его.

Comment: Вы не будете против, если я правкой ответ на пункты разделю?.. =)